# NSIS Install to program files doesn't get access to dependecies

Tags: python, pyinstaller, bundle, executable, nsis

I have a python executable created with pyinstaller. I created an installer with NSIS the installer and program (python executable) work perfectly when I install the program folder to the desktop (obviously this isn't where the program folder goes). When I set the program folder to program files the installer work fine but the app doesn't work as expected. Specifically the dependencies on the database (sqlite3) font and images, all in their respective folders in the main program folder. The initial state of the app loads fine with images and DB data but as soon as the queries for images and DB data start the program crashes. I can't test to find the problem since the source code works fine without problems and since the program works fine when the program directory is installed to the desktop the problem is either with pyinstaller or NSIS (I don't have much experience with this. I'm mainly a web developer.) I used NSIS Quick Setup Script Generator to create an nsi script. here is my pyinstaller arguments --onefile --windowed and below is my nsi generated script I have three dependent folders database fonts and images. the images arent static and change based on user input. Any advice or docs would be great

```
!define APP_NAME "appname"
!define COMP_NAME "COMPANY"
!define WEB_SITE "Website"
!define VERSION "1.00.00.00"
!define COPYRIGHT "Website � 2021"
!define DESCRIPTION "Application"
!define INSTALLER_NAME "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free Setup.exe"
!define MAIN_APP_EXE "appname Free.exe"
!define INSTALL_TYPE "SetShellVarContext current"
!define REG_ROOT "HKCU"
!define REG_APP_PATH "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\${MAIN_APP_EXE}"
!define UNINSTALL_PATH "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${APP_NAME}"
!define MUI_ICON "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free 1.0.0\images\appname2.ico"



VIProductVersion  "${VERSION}"
VIAddVersionKey "ProductName"  "${APP_NAME}"
VIAddVersionKey "CompanyName"  "${COMP_NAME}"
VIAddVersionKey "LegalCopyright"  "${COPYRIGHT}"
VIAddVersionKey "FileDescription"  "${DESCRIPTION}"
VIAddVersionKey "FileVersion"  "${VERSION}"



SetCompressor ZLIB
Name "${APP_NAME}"
Caption "${APP_NAME}"
OutFile "${INSTALLER_NAME}"
BrandingText "${APP_NAME}"
XPStyle on
InstallDirRegKey "${REG_ROOT}" "${REG_APP_PATH}" ""
InstallDir "$DESKTOP\appname"



!include "MUI.nsh"

!define MUI_ABORTWARNING
!define MUI_UNABORTWARNING

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME

!ifdef LICENSE_TXT
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "${LICENSE_TXT}"
!endif

!ifdef REG_START_MENU
!define MUI_STARTMENUPAGE_NODISABLE
!define MUI_STARTMENUPAGE_DEFAULTFOLDER "appname Free"
!define MUI_STARTMENUPAGE_REGISTRY_ROOT "${REG_ROOT}"
!define MUI_STARTMENUPAGE_REGISTRY_KEY "${UNINSTALL_PATH}"
!define MUI_STARTMENUPAGE_REGISTRY_VALUENAME "${REG_START_MENU}"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_STARTMENU Application $SM_Folder
!endif

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES

!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN "$INSTDIR\${MAIN_APP_EXE}"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH

!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM

!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES

!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_FINISH

!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"



Section -MainProgram
${INSTALL_TYPE}
SetOverwrite ifnewer
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
File "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free 1.0.0\main.py"
File "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free 1.0.0\appname Free.exe"
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\images"
File "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free 1.0.0\images\AppsIconBlack.png"
File "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free 1.0.0\images\AppsIconWhite.png"
File "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free 1.0.0\images\cross.png"
File "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free 1.0.0\images\dropdown.png"
File "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free 1.0.0\images\NotesIconBlack.png"
File "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free 1.0.0\images\NotesIconWhite.png"
File "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free 1.0.0\images\radio-off.png"
File "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free 1.0.0\images\radio-on.png"
File "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free 1.0.0\images\SettingIconBlack.png"
File "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free 1.0.0\images\SettingsIconWhite.png"
File "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free 1.0.0\images\tick.png"
File "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free 1.0.0\images\toggle-off.png"
File "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free 1.0.0\images\toggle-on.png"
File "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free 1.0.0\images\appname.png"
File "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free 1.0.0\images\appname2.ico"
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\fonts"
File "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free 1.0.0\fonts\Nunito-Regular.ttf"
File "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free 1.0.0\fonts\Nunito-SemiBoldItalic.ttf"
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\database"
File "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free 1.0.0\database\db.py"
File "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free 1.0.0\database\runner.db"
SectionEnd



Section -Additional
SetOutPath "$APPDATA\${APP_NAME}"
File "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free 1.0.0\main.py"
File "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free 1.0.0\appname Free.exe"
SetOutPath "$APPDATA\${APP_NAME}\images"
File "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free 1.0.0\images\AppsIconBlack.png"
File "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free 1.0.0\images\AppsIconWhite.png"
File "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free 1.0.0\images\cross.png"
File "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free 1.0.0\images\dropdown.png"
File "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free 1.0.0\images\NotesIconBlack.png"
File "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free 1.0.0\images\NotesIconWhite.png"
File "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free 1.0.0\images\radio-off.png"
File "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free 1.0.0\images\radio-on.png"
File "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free 1.0.0\images\SettingIconBlack.png"
File "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free 1.0.0\images\SettingsIconWhite.png"
File "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free 1.0.0\images\tick.png"
File "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free 1.0.0\images\toggle-off.png"
File "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free 1.0.0\images\toggle-on.png"
File "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free 1.0.0\images\appname.png"
File "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free 1.0.0\images\appname2.ico"
SetOutPath "$APPDATA\${APP_NAME}\fonts"
File "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free 1.0.0\fonts\Nunito-Regular.ttf"
File "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free 1.0.0\fonts\Nunito-SemiBoldItalic.ttf"
SetOutPath "$APPDATA\${APP_NAME}\database"
File "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free 1.0.0\database\db.py"
File "C:\Users\SATRUST\OneDrive\Desktop\appname Free 1.0.0\database\runner.db"
SectionEnd



Section -Icons_Reg
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
WriteUninstaller "$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe"

!ifdef REG_START_MENU
!insertmacro MUI_STARTMENU_WRITE_BEGIN Application
CreateDirectory "$SMPROGRAMS\$SM_Folder"
CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\$SM_Folder\${APP_NAME}.lnk" "$INSTDIR\${MAIN_APP_EXE}"
CreateShortCut "$DESKTOP\${APP_NAME}.lnk" "$INSTDIR\${MAIN_APP_EXE}"
!ifdef WEB_SITE
WriteIniStr "$INSTDIR\${APP_NAME} website.url" "InternetShortcut" "URL" "${WEB_SITE}"
CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\$SM_Folder\${APP_NAME} Website.lnk" "$INSTDIR\${APP_NAME} website.url"
!endif
!insertmacro MUI_STARTMENU_WRITE_END
!endif

!ifndef REG_START_MENU
CreateDirectory "$SMPROGRAMS\appname Free"
CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\appname Free\${APP_NAME}.lnk" "$INSTDIR\${MAIN_APP_EXE}"
CreateShortCut "$DESKTOP\${APP_NAME}.lnk" "$INSTDIR\${MAIN_APP_EXE}"
!ifdef WEB_SITE
WriteIniStr "$INSTDIR\${APP_NAME} website.url" "InternetShortcut" "URL" "${WEB_SITE}"
CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\appname Free\${APP_NAME} Website.lnk" "$INSTDIR\${APP_NAME} website.url"
!endif
!endif

WriteRegStr ${REG_ROOT} "${REG_APP_PATH}" "" "$INSTDIR\${MAIN_APP_EXE}"
WriteRegStr ${REG_ROOT} "${UNINSTALL_PATH}"  "DisplayName" "${APP_NAME}"
WriteRegStr ${REG_ROOT} "${UNINSTALL_PATH}"  "UninstallString" "$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe"
WriteRegStr ${REG_ROOT} "${UNINSTALL_PATH}"  "DisplayIcon" "$INSTDIR\${MAIN_APP_EXE}"
WriteRegStr ${REG_ROOT} "${UNINSTALL_PATH}"  "DisplayVersion" "${VERSION}"
WriteRegStr ${REG_ROOT} "${UNINSTALL_PATH}"  "Publisher" "${COMP_NAME}"

!ifdef WEB_SITE
WriteRegStr ${REG_ROOT} "${UNINSTALL_PATH}"  "URLInfoAbout" "${WEB_SITE}"
!endif
SectionEnd



Section Uninstall
${INSTALL_TYPE}
Delete "$INSTDIR\main.py"
Delete "$INSTDIR\appname Free.exe"
Delete "$INSTDIR\images\AppsIconBlack.png"
Delete "$INSTDIR\images\AppsIconWhite.png"
Delete "$INSTDIR\images\cross.png"
Delete "$INSTDIR\images\dropdown.png"
Delete "$INSTDIR\images\NotesIconBlack.png"
Delete "$INSTDIR\images\NotesIconWhite.png"
Delete "$INSTDIR\images\radio-off.png"
Delete "$INSTDIR\images\radio-on.png"
Delete "$INSTDIR\images\SettingIconBlack.png"
Delete "$INSTDIR\images\SettingsIconWhite.png"
Delete "$INSTDIR\images\tick.png"
Delete "$INSTDIR\images\toggle-off.png"
Delete "$INSTDIR\images\toggle-on.png"
Delete "$INSTDIR\images\appname.png"
Delete "$INSTDIR\images\appname2.ico"
Delete "$INSTDIR\fonts\Nunito-Regular.ttf"
Delete "$INSTDIR\fonts\Nunito-SemiBoldItalic.ttf"
Delete "$INSTDIR\database\db.py"
Delete "$INSTDIR\database\runner.db"


RmDir "$INSTDIR\database"
RmDir "$INSTDIR\fonts"
RmDir "$INSTDIR\images"

 
Delete "$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe"
!ifdef WEB_SITE
Delete "$INSTDIR\${APP_NAME} website.url"
!endif

RmDir "$INSTDIR"

!ifndef NEVER_UNINSTALL
Delete "$APPDATA\${APP_NAME}\main.py"
Delete "$APPDATA\${APP_NAME}\appname Free.exe"
Delete "$APPDATA\${APP_NAME}\images\AppsIconBlack.png"
Delete "$APPDATA\${APP_NAME}\images\AppsIconWhite.png"
Delete "$APPDATA\${APP_NAME}\images\cross.png"
Delete "$APPDATA\${APP_NAME}\images\dropdown.png"
Delete "$APPDATA\${APP_NAME}\images\NotesIconBlack.png"
Delete "$APPDATA\${APP_NAME}\images\NotesIconWhite.png"
Delete "$APPDATA\${APP_NAME}\images\radio-off.png"
Delete "$APPDATA\${APP_NAME}\images\radio-on.png"
Delete "$APPDATA\${APP_NAME}\images\SettingIconBlack.png"
Delete "$APPDATA\${APP_NAME}\images\SettingsIconWhite.png"
Delete "$APPDATA\${APP_NAME}\images\tick.png"
Delete "$APPDATA\${APP_NAME}\images\toggle-off.png"
Delete "$APPDATA\${APP_NAME}\images\toggle-on.png"
Delete "$APPDATA\${APP_NAME}\images\appname.png"
Delete "$APPDATA\${APP_NAME}\images\appname2.ico"
Delete "$APPDATA\${APP_NAME}\fonts\Nunito-Regular.ttf"
Delete "$APPDATA\${APP_NAME}\fonts\Nunito-SemiBoldItalic.ttf"
Delete "$APPDATA\${APP_NAME}\database\db.py"
Delete "$APPDATA\${APP_NAME}\database\runner.db"
 
RmDir "$APPDATA\${APP_NAME}\database"
RmDir "$APPDATA\${APP_NAME}\fonts"
RmDir "$APPDATA\${APP_NAME}\images"

 
RmDir "$APPDATA\${APP_NAME}"
!endif

!ifdef REG_START_MENU
!insertmacro MUI_STARTMENU_GETFOLDER "Application" $SM_Folder
Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\$SM_Folder\${APP_NAME}.lnk"
!ifdef WEB_SITE
Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\$SM_Folder\${APP_NAME} Website.lnk"
!endif
Delete "$DESKTOP\${APP_NAME}.lnk"

RmDir "$SMPROGRAMS\$SM_Folder"
!endif

!ifndef REG_START_MENU
Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\appname Free\${APP_NAME}.lnk"
!ifdef WEB_SITE
Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\appname Free\${APP_NAME} Website.lnk"
!endif
Delete "$DESKTOP\${APP_NAME}.lnk"

RmDir "$SMPROGRAMS\appname Free"
!endif

DeleteRegKey ${REG_ROOT} "${REG_APP_PATH}"
DeleteRegKey ${REG_ROOT} "${UNINSTALL_PATH}"
SectionEnd
```

Comment: The problem is with python, not NSIS. You are probably loading files relative to the current directory instead of the program directory.

Comment: If you are trying to write to the database, that might also be an issue. Apps are not supposed to write to files in the program files folder.

Comment: Thank you for the help, using absolute values will solve the images problem. I didn't know you couldn't write to files in the program files. Do you by any chance know how I can write to a database that is stored locally?

Comment: I did some research and found the standard way to use a local database on windows 10. here are some helpful links for anyone struggling with the same issue. https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/798662/How-can-I-write-to-program-files-x-folder   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/sidebar/system-environment-getenvironmentvariable?redirectedfrom=MSDN